# Unable to execute native binaries file in MacOS?

Tags: java, macos, jar, native

I have found a Java application repository on GitHub which provides the application in JAR format and in the native binary format for different operating systems such as MacOS, Windows, Linux.

I am able to execute the JAR file using the `java -jar` command but I would like to run the native binary file so users can execute it without installing the Java in their system.

Can someone please inform me how can I run the binary file on Macos? I tried to search and found the command `chmod +x name-of-binary` but this command does not do anything.

I am really new to this and do not have much idea about this so any suggestion would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way would be to either open a terminal and manually running the binary, like so:

```
./<name-of-file>
```

This would only work if you are running the file in a user who has execution privileges on that file. if you run into trouble with priviliges, that's where I would use chmod.
If you need any more specific help, I would recommend posting the link to that GitHub repo for us to look at, and telling us what is it that it should do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I tried as you mentioned and I get the following pop-up: `“name-of-binary” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.`. Generally what should happen and how can I work-around this issue?

Comment: if my answer helped you in anyway, can you please accept it?
about your other question, can you copy and paste the exact input given and output received? (a new question would be the best)

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by allowing the permission under security & privacy of the system preferences. Thanks for the response, I have accepted it.